# Is there a central database of citation styles for latex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I have been considering migrating to Latex to write my academic papers, but I'm struggling with how to manage citations properly.

When publishing a paper, I often have a cycle of submit-reject-submit to another journal. Often those journals have very specific bibliographic styles (whether years have parenthesis, authors surnames come first or not, etc.).

In Word with Mendeley/Zotero/Endnote, it is easy to change references styles since these programs have a central database of CSL styles and have one for (almost) every journal.

Is there a similar database for Bibtex/Biblatex styles?

I tried googling, but I could find only the most basic reference styles (author-year, numbered), or absurdly famous journals (like Nature), where I can only dream of publishing.

Comment: There exist various journal styles both for bibtex and biblatex, but there is no central organization, some are maintained by the journal, some by voluntary work.

Comment: Many journals and conferences provide their own custom bibliography style files on their website for download, or detailed instructions on using standard styles (although sometimes you need to sign up for some submission system before you get access to such files or information). So the workflow is 1. choose a conference or journal 2. visit their website 3. download and apply the prescribed bibliography style. This may not be as easy as a central database but probably you are visiting the website anyway so it's not much extra work.